# Transparency and Depth test in Pyglet

Tags: transparency, pyglet, depth-buffer

I am trying to render a scene with partially transparent sprites in Pyglet.
I want to activate z depth test to render them but this yields the following:

[two images overlapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIOxU.png)

The two images incorrectly overlap.

The code I use is the following

```
import pyglet as pg
from pyglet.gl import *

window = pg.window.Window(width=320, height=320)
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
glEnable(GL_BLEND)
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
batch = pg.graphics.Batch()

im1 = pg.image.load(
    'resources/sprites/npc/soldier/walk/0.png')
sprite1 = pg.sprite.Sprite(im1, x=100, y=100, z=1, batch=batch)
im2 = pg.image.load(
    'resources/sprites/npc/soldier/walk/0.png')
sprite2 = pg.sprite.Sprite(im2, x=150, y=150, z=0, batch=batch)

@window.event
def on_draw():
    window.clear()
    batch.draw()

pg.app.run()
```

The image I use is here [npc_walking](https://github.com/StanislavPetrovV/DOOM-style-Game/blob/main/resources/sprites/npc/soldier/walk/0.png)

As you can see in the code, I tried blending but this has no effect.

I also tried  `glEnable(GL_ALPHA_TEST)` (cf [opengl z-sorting transparency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984887/opengl-z-sorting-transparency?rq=2)) but since it is deprecated, I don't know how to use the discard solution in Pyglet.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a solution,

It was indeed to discard fragments with 0 transparency but since GL_ALPHA_TEST is discarded you have to write some OpenGL code.

To do that in Pyglet, add the following at the beginning of your code

```
pyglet.sprite.fragment_source = """#version 150 core
in vec4 vertex_colors;
in vec3 texture_coords;
out vec4 final_colors;

uniform sampler2D sprite_texture;

void main()
{
    final_colors = texture(sprite_texture, texture_coords.xy) * vertex_colors;
    if (final_colors.a == 0) discard;
} """
```

Comment: Looks like you found the solution. There is an example of depth sprite in pyglet examples: https://github.com/pyglet/pyglet/blob/master/examples/sprite/depth_sprite.py